# Cassic ASP in VB Redirect issues

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I've inherited a classic ASP site that has developed an odd problem. At the top of the page its redirecting to https for a secure connections. The code is:

```
<%
Response.Buffer = True

' Redirect to SSL if needed:
servername=Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME")
scriptname=Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")
serverport=Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_PORT")

if serverport="80" and (InStr(servername, "192.168.1.") = 0 and servername <> "localhost")  then
    Response.Redirect "https://www.theurl.com" & scriptname & "?package=" + Request.QueryString("package")
else
    'response.Write("Development testing")
end if

%>
```

This code is at the top of the file. Nothing is before this. When I open the browser and load up the page I age a:

```
Response object error 'ASP 0156 : 80004005'

The HTTP headers are already written to the client browser. Any HTTP header modifications must be made before writing page content.
```

No redirect happend. If I reload the page or go away and come back after the error then everything works just fine until I close the browser and reopen it.

If this is at the top of the file how can the headers already be written?

**Update:** The full source as provided by IE8's view source:

```
 <font face="Arial" size=2>
<p>Response object</font> <font face="Arial" size=2>error 'ASP 0156 : 80004005'</font>
<p>
<font face="Arial" size=2>Header Error</font>
<p>
<font face="Arial" size=2>/path/file.asp</font><font face="Arial" size=2>, line 10</font>
<p>
<font face="Arial" size=2>The HTTP headers are already written to the client browser. Any HTTP header modifications must be made before writing page content.
</font>
```

Yes the space before

Comment: Is Buffering enabled for the virtual directory in IIS?

Comment: @Sparky - Yes its set to true.

Comment: When you get the error, if you do a View Source, do you see anything other than the error message.   Any character in the file could trigger this.   Based on the code above, it doesn't appear that there should be, but somehow, something is getting into the response stream.  The fact that CLEAR didn't help makes me think it is coming from source other source.

Comment: @Sparky - I Listed the source above.

Comment: Everything except the space is from the VB error handler, it could be the space causing the problem.  Just for fun, try only putting the redirect in (just some generic site).   If that works, add each line back in.   Also try removing the response.buffer=true, that may write something out to the header...

Answer (score 1):

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/159402

Add `Response.Clear` before and `Response.End` after the `Response.Redirect`.